# android - How properly set clickListener in adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have below logic in my adapter :

```
 val listItem = modelCart[position]

    var number = 0
        holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            val textNumber = number++
            listItem.amount = textNumber.toString()
            holder.amount.text = listItem.amount
        }
```

My purpose is when clickListener(btnAdd) is called on each item the amount of that position increased by one .

In above logic there is no issue and the amount of each item increased by one when calling clickListner .

But I think is the better idea to declare the logic not to the adapter directly .
I'm using an interface to actually declare the above logic in my corresponding fragment .

So in my adapter I declared an interface :

ClickListner Interface

```
interface ClickListener {
    fun onClick(modelCart: ModelCart , textView: TextView)
}
```

and declare a instance of that in my constructor adapter :

```
class MarketAdapter(
    private val modelCart: List<ModelCart> , private val clickListener: ClickListener
)
```

The below code for having better sight of my adapter :

```
 class ViewHolder(itemview: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview)

        val amount = itemview.amount_market
        val btnAdd = itemview.add_market


 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)

 val listItem = modelCart[position]

// where the clickListner called .
 holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.onClick(listItem , holder.amount)
        }
```

and in my fragment I get the interface :

```
  val list = ArrayList<ModelCart>()
        for (i in 0..50) {
            list.add(ModelCart(amount = "0", title ="pizza",price = "10$",image = R.drawable.pizza))
        }
        model = list
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Market)

        recyclerView.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(view.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        recyclerView.adapter =

            MarketAdapter(model, object : ClickListener{
                var number = 0
                override fun onClick(modelCart: ModelCart , textView: TextView) {
                    modelCart.amount = number++.toString()
                    textView.text = modelCart.amount
                }
            })
```

This logic not work well !!! I don't know exactly what happening in here .

This must work like this : each time the clickListner is called , the amount of each position should increased . but this is not happend !!! what's wrong with the second logic ? how can I fix this ?

So if anyone can help me with this , I'll be much appreciated .

Comment: You just write the logic doesn't work well. What does not work? What is the wrong behaviour?

Comment: stop inlining onclick methods. create a class to extend onclick events and give it the number in constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't pass your listener to your adapater  ?

```
    class MarketAdapter(
    private val modelCart: List<ModelCart> ,val clickListener: (ModelCart, TextView) -> Unit
    ){
     override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int ) {
            holder.bind(modelCart[position], clickListener)
        }
}
```

After in your viewHolder :

```
class ViewHolder(itemview: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview)
fun bind(modelCart: ModelCart?, clickListener: (ModelCart, TextView) -> Unit)){
   holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener {clickListener(modelCart, holder.)}
}
```

And in fragment/ Activity

```
fun increaseValue(modelCart : ModelCart, view : TextView){
val textNumber = modelCart.amount.toInt()
textNumber++ 
modelCart.amount = textNumber.toString()
view.text = modelCart.amount

}
```

For initialization :

```
MarketAdapter(model,  { modelCart: ModelCart, view:TextView -> increaseValue(modelCart, view) }
            })
```

I think your code is good, but I don't understand your callback/interface ClickListener . I wrote it quickly may be there're some syntax errors